# Taylor series of an entire function converges locally uniformly.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an entire function, prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(z)}{n!}$ converges locally uniformly in $\mathbb{C}$

Should I prove this by first fixing an open disk, and then use Weierstrass M test?
thank you

Comment: Fixing an arbitrary bounded set, using the Cauchy estimates and then finishing it with Weierstraß is a good plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every power series converges uniformly in a circle of radius $r<R$, where $R$ is the convergence radius. For an entire function, $R=\infty$, for the Taylor series around any $z_0.$
Edit: that would be the answer to the question in the title. The question in the body is different:
Let $M(R)=\sup_{|z|=R}f(z)$. Then, $$f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_{|t|=R}\frac{f(t)}{(t-z)^{n+1}}\,dt,$$ and that means
$$\left|\frac{f^{(n)}(z)}{n!}\right|\le\frac{R\,M(R)}{(R-|z|)^{n+1}}.$$
So that's converging locally uniformly, too.